# how to test types (long, short, byte) with junit

Tags: java, junit

I need to test if the data type is correct. For example, if I type "Test", I unit test with junit. I am not able to unit test the types: float, short, byte and long. I have no idea how to do it, I've already researched it!

I managed to test the types: char, double, string, boolean.

Can you help me please?  IDE: Intellij

```
public interface Cell {

    Optional<Integer> asInteger();

    Optional<String> asString();

    RequiredCell notNull();

    boolean isNotNull();

    Optional<Object> asObject();

    Optional<Float> asFloat();

    Optional<Double> asDouble();

    Optional<Character> asChar();

    Optional<Short> asShort();

    Optional<Byte> asByte();

    Optional<Long> asLong();

    Optional<Boolean> asBoolean();

}
```

```
public class CellImpl implements Cell {

    private final RowImpl row;
    private final Column column;
    public final Object value;

    public CellImpl(final RowImpl row, final Column column, final Object value) {
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Integer> asInteger() {
        if (value instanceof Integer) {
            return Optional.ofNullable((Integer)value);
        }
        return Optional.ofNullable(null);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<String> asString() {
        if (value instanceof String) {
            return Optional.ofNullable((String)value);
        }
        return Optional.ofNullable(null);
    }



    @Override
    public RequiredCell notNull() {
        if (value == null) {
            throw new SQLException(SQLErrorCode.SF002_REQUIRED_CELL_IS_NULL, column.getName(), String.valueOf(row.getIndex()));
        }
        return new RequiredCellImpl(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNotNull() {
        return value != null;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Object> asObject() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(value);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Float> asFloat() {
        if (value instanceof Float) {
            return Optional.ofNullable((Float)value);
        }
        return Optional.ofNullable(null);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Double> asDouble() {
        if (value instanceof Double) {
            return Optional.ofNullable((Double)value);
        }
        return Optional.ofNullable(null);

    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Character> asChar() {
        if (value instanceof Character) {
            return Optional.ofNullable((Character)value);
        }
        return Optional.ofNullable(null);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Short> asShort() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(cast(Short.class));
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Byte> asByte() {
        if (value instanceof Byte) {
            return Optional.ofNullable((Byte)value);
        }
        return Optional.ofNullable(null);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Long> asLong() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(cast(Long.class));
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Boolean> asBoolean() {

        if (value instanceof Boolean) {
            return Optional.ofNullable((Boolean)value);
        }
        return Optional.ofNullable(null);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T cast(final Class<T> clazz) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (!clazz.equals(value.getClass())){
            throw new SQLException(SQLErrorCode.SF003_INCOMPATIBLE_DATA_TYPE, column.getName(), String.valueOf(row.getIndex()),
                    clazz.getSimpleName(), value.getClass().getSimpleName());
        }
        return (T) value;
    }

    Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

```
class CellImplTest {

    @Test
    void asInteger() {
        CellImpl teste = new CellImpl(null, null, 3);
        assertEquals(3, teste.notNull().asInteger());
    }

    @Test
    void asDouble() {
        CellImpl teste = new CellImpl(null, null, 3.2);
        assertEquals(3.2, teste.notNull().asDouble());
    }

    @Test
    void asString() {
        CellImpl teste = new CellImpl(null, null, "TesteString");
        //assertEquals("TesteString", teste.notNull().asString());
        assertEquals("TesteString", teste.notNull().asString());

    }



    @Test
    void asBoolean() {
        CellImpl teste = new CellImpl(null,null, true);
        assertEquals(true, teste.notNull().asBoolean());
        }


    @Test
    void asChar() {
        CellImpl teste = new CellImpl(null, null, 'A');
        //assertEquals("Character",teste.asChar().get().getClass().getSimpleName());
        //System.out.println(teste.asChar().get().getClass().getSimpleName());
        //System.out.println(teste.notNull().asChar());
        assertEquals('A',teste.notNull().asChar());
    }
}
```

Comment: Use literals or cast. `3.2F` makes it a float. For shorts and bytes you need to cast `(byte) 5` and `(short) 5`. What also works is to just have it in two separate lines instead of inlining it, as in having a variable `short x = 5;` and then using that variable instead.

Comment: nice, very thank you, it worked out

Comment: @CyberMaique You can self-answer to share the fixed code

Comment: how do I do that?